# Who are "brown" communities in the US?

Tags: meaning

When Americans say "black and brown communities", who do they mean by "brown"? (Native Americans? Indians? Hispanics? Latinos?)

(Some context: I am a non-American fan of the NBA and while watching many NBA-related videos in recent months, this is a term that has occasionally popped up. The context is usually about "helping"/"fighting for" "black and brown communities".)

Comment: The meaning of "brown" varies with speaker/writer and the era of the utterance/writing.  There was a time (the 60s, I'm thinking) when "black" was considered derogatory when used to describe people of African descent, plus there was the recognition that many such people actually had a much lighter skin tone -- one that was not well-described with "black".   So "brown" was substituted for "black".  This was when "yellow" was still used to describe Asians, and "red" was used to describe Native Americans.  The terminology has been jumbled several times.

Answer (score 0):

They mean people of color other than Blacks, Native Americans, and Oriental Asians (as opposed to Asian Indians). You will find a lot of younger (under 50) Asian Indian-Americans and Pakistani-Americans who are not first generation Americans refer to themselves as Brown or a Brown community. This may just be a function of my being around more Asian Indians than Middle Easterners. Asians, in general, make up a large percentage of my neighborhood. Many Mexican-Americans (as opposed to continental Spanish) will do the same. I rarely come across Middle Eastern-Americans using the term to refer to themselves. Though, it may be more prominent in other regions of the US.

Comment: So anyone who is not black, white, or East Asian could be "brown"? What about those of Southeast Asian descent who aren't Chinese/Vietnamese (Filipinos, Thais, Malays, etc.)?

Comment: @user135187 - *Could be*. It is better to err on the side of caution. Use the term only when familiar with the person. After all, there are many Caribbean, Central American, and South American immigrants and descendants with African ancestry that do not consider themselves Black. Combine that with the Colored Race of South Africa and you have a lot of ambiguity. Arbitrarily assigning someone as Brown might be considered offensive to that person. Effectively, Black America is more of a culture than it is a race. So is Brown.

Comment: After all, if it was all about skin color, there would be very few white or black people amongst the Whites and Blacks. The same is true regarding Filipinos and Asian Indians, two cultures I am intimately familiar. Some may be paler than the average White person or darker than the average Black person. I have Filipino friends who could pass for Japanese and others who could be dark Puerto Rican, Dominican, Mexican or mulatto. They would mostly be considered Brown.